# python codon translator input check

Tags: python, input

I'm stuck in the error checking of a codon translator which translate codons to corresponding amino acids. I have the codon table in a dictionary. Now I would like to check two different input errors:

1. Input like "JFK" should show an error which indicate it's not a codon
2. Input like "JF" should show an error which indicate it's not a codon and it's not a three-base code.

Comment: Read this, please: http://v.gd/whathaveyoutried

Comment: how does the hash table look like?

Comment: Why is `"JFK"` not a codon? What are the rules for determining that? I don't think the average Python programmer is all that familiar with DNA sequencing / analysis.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how it is determined, he's got a table of valid translations, if it isn't in the table, it isn't valid.

Comment: @Perkins Ok, then _that_ is the rule for determining validity. He should have stated that.

Answer (score 1):

```
codon = raw_input()
if len(codon) != 3:
  print "Not a codon/3 letter based."
elif codon not in codonHash:
  print "Not a codon"
else:
  acid = codonHash[codon]
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: @user1691379 Then please upvote this answer and accept it. Also you should answer follow-up questions that people ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your codons in a dictionary, you could just try to look up the potential codon and catch the resulting error.

```
def check_codon(codon):
    try:
        acid = codonTable[codon]
    except KeyError:
        if len(codon) != 3:
            return "Not a codon, not a three-base code"
        else:
            return "Not a codon"

>>> print check_codon("JFK")
"Not a codon"
>>> print check_codon("JK")
"Not a codon, not a three-base code"
```

Comment: Should be if len(codon) != 3:
Codons are all 3 base pair sequences.